# javascript variable always undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, redirect

When I want to redirect, the variable **where** is always udefined. But, for example, I want put that variable in `alert();` it shows correct number.

code

```
var where = msg.txt;
window.location = "/page.php?id=".where; //this redirects to /page.php?id=undefined
alert(where); //it show correct number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, `.` is used for property access, not for string concatenation like in PHP.

Use `+` instead:

```
window.location = "/page.php?id=" + where;
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
window.location = "/page.php?id=" + where;
```

You have:

```
"/page.php?id=".where;
```

Which tries to retrieve a `where` property of a string, and such has not been defined.